# Ensuring projects in solution are from same TFS branch

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs, add-in

Is there an available way to identify if there is any project in a solution or reference in a project which is from another TFS source branch?
The goal is to prevent this by alerting users before a check-in or while adding that project/reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not the most efficient way, but a band-aid we used...

We setup a gated checkin build that only checks out the specific source directory for that branch. Any references above or outside the branch root throws an error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I very much like this approach over custom check-in policies since check-in policies are able to be overridden (by design).  The Gated CI build will be able to detect pending changes that can affect the compilation process or anything else for that matter.

Comment: Did a +1 as I like the approach. Would wait for some time to see if any other options are posted before marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to get what you need with a custom [Checkin-Policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181281%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
A very nice How-To on implementing one, can be found in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/03/31/how-to-implement-package-and-deploy-custom-check-in-policy-for-tfs-2010.aspx) great article by J.Lamb. In here, author focuses on auditing if prior to checkin [NArrange](http://www.narrange.net/) was executed, it should be possible to exchange that with auditing for the placement of all sources under a given root in source control.
After you have constructed & deployed this policy and with [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) installed, you should apply the already available policy 'Custom Path Policy' on your newly constructed policy. You can find [here](http://leon.mvps.org/Tfs/MergeOnlyPolicy.html) an example. You need this in order to scope your checkin policy on the solution directory and not the whole TeamProject.